# SQL Server Return All Sub Categories

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two tables in SQL Server 2008 R2:

`tblCategories`

- `cat_id`
- `cat_name`

`tblCategoryHierarchy`

- `cat_parent_id`
- `cat_child_id`

There can any number of levels, and any number of sub-categories under each category. Changing the table structure is not possible.

What I'm looking to do, is provide one `cat_id` and return ALL `cat_id`'s under it within the hierarchy, no matter how many levels there are.

For example (`tblCategoryHierarchy`):

`cat_parent_id  cat_child_id
101            200
101            201
101            202
101            203
202            300
202            301`

- 100
- 101

  - 200
  - 201
  - 202

    - 300
    - 301
  - 203
- 102

If I provide `cat_id` 101, I need to return: 200, 201, 202, 300, 301 and 203.

I've attempted this with VB but I had lots and lots of queries and it was very slow. So I'm looking for a pure SQL solution, which I'm hoping will be fast and not take up too many server resources.

A store procedure sounds good to me, so is there a good way to achieve what I need this way..?

Comment: You'll need a CTE, If you are doing this for all data it will be more efficient to do this in VB, you are just doing it wrong.

Comment: can you give us some sample data of both the tables and relationship between them?

Comment: Sample data is under 'For example:', that's from the `tblCategoryHierarchy` table, which I've now labelled (I will also add a list too in a moment). I guess I don't need to show you the `tblCategories` table because the hierarchy is done in `tblCategoryHierarchy`.

Comment: Both `cat_parent_id` and  `cat_child_id` hold `cat_id`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive common-table expression (CTE).

Something like this below should do it. Here X = 4 is a
constant: your input `cat_id` (200 in your example).

```
WITH CatCTE (cat_id) AS
(
    SELECT t.cat_id
    FROM tblCategories t
    WHERE t.cat_id = 4

    UNION ALL

    SELECT P.cat_child_id as cat_id
    FROM CatCTE AS m
    JOIN tblCategoryHierarchy AS P on m.cat_id = P.cat_parent_id

)
SELECT cat_id
FROM CatCTE
WHERE
cat_id <> 4;
```

**SCRIPT which creates some testing data:**

```
create table tblCategories(cat_id int, cat_name varchar(20));

create table tblCategoryHierarchy(cat_parent_id int, cat_child_id int);

insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values ( 1, 'cat 1');
insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values ( 2, 'cat 2');
insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values ( 3, 'cat 3');
insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values ( 4, 'cat 4');
insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values ( 5, 'cat 5');

insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values ( 6, 'cat 6');
insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values ( 7, 'cat 7');
insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values ( 8, 'cat 8');
insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values ( 9, 'cat 9');
insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values (10, 'cat 10');

insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values (11, 'cat 11');
insert into tblCategories(cat_id, cat_name) values (12, 'cat 12');

insert into tblCategoryHierarchy (cat_parent_id, cat_child_id) values ( 1, 2);
insert into tblCategoryHierarchy (cat_parent_id, cat_child_id) values ( 1, 3);

insert into tblCategoryHierarchy (cat_parent_id, cat_child_id) values ( 4, 6);
insert into tblCategoryHierarchy (cat_parent_id, cat_child_id) values ( 4, 8);

insert into tblCategoryHierarchy (cat_parent_id, cat_child_id) values ( 8, 10);
insert into tblCategoryHierarchy (cat_parent_id, cat_child_id) values ( 8, 11);

insert into tblCategoryHierarchy (cat_parent_id, cat_child_id) values (11, 12);

insert into tblCategoryHierarchy (cat_parent_id, cat_child_id) values ( 5, 7);
insert into tblCategoryHierarchy (cat_parent_id, cat_child_id) values ( 5, 9);
```

Comment: Let me try to prepare a real example for you and to test my idea.

Comment: OK, yes, this works fine. Here is SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdabbc/1

Comment: Now, if you want, I think you can turn this into a stored procedure (SP) and make the X=4 a parameter of the SP.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you, getting all the hierarchy once will offer better performance then getting it one branch at a time via multiple calls.

```
-- Here we will store the hierarchy
Dim parentToChild As New Dictionary(Of Integer, IList(Of Int))()

...

-- How you get to here depends on how you access your database,
-- somewhere between ADO.Net and EF.
-- The command simply retrieves all rows from [tblCategoryHierarchy]
-- Column 0 is [cat_parent_id], Column 1 is [cat_child_id]
Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Dim parent = reader.GetInt32(0)
        If Not parentToChild.ContainsKey(parent) Then
            parentToChild.Add(parent, New List(Of Integer))
        End If

        parentToChild(parent).Add(reader.GetInt32(1))
    End While
End Using

...
```

This way you can load the hierarchy into a dictionary allowing you a fast lookup.

The next step rather depends on what you want to do with the hierarchy.

If you make this extension method

```
<Extension()>
Public Shared Function Traverse(Of MyNode)( _
        ByVal root As MyNode,
        ByVal childSelector As Function(Of MyNode, IEnumerable(Of MyNode))
            As IEnumerable(Of MyNode)

    Dim stack = New Stack(Of MyNode)()
    stack.Push(root)
    While stack.Count > 0
        Dim current = stack.Pop()
        Yield current
        For Each Dim child In childSelector(current)
            stack.Push(child)
        Next
    End While
End Function
```

you can trivially iterate through all the children of `200`, for example, by doing,

```
Dim children = 200.Traverse(Function(parent) parentToChild(parent))
For Each child In children
    ...
Next
```

---

If the hierarchy changes often, on multiple threads or, you only need one branch or lineage of the hierarchy, use [Peter Petrov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26862930/659190) answer.